# Batch file - I see 3 different solutions, but how

Tags: batch-processing

I am trying to rename and move a file every 120 seconds to a new folder, but in the source folder structure one of the folders is changing every day, the foldername is based on the date.

Example:
MOVE D:\OneDrive\Serienummer\01\2017-03-05\PIC\NVR_ch01*.jpg D:\WEBCAMS\Testkamera\0101.jpg

This works fine, but I need to change the: \2017-03-05\ tomorrow.
To do this manually is not a option!

So is there a way to have a code that will use todays date dynamically?

or

is there a way to grab all files under D:\OneDrive\Serienummer\and move them to the designated new folder location even if the datefolder will change every day?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current year, month, day and have new path every day:

```
set year=%date:~6,4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set path = D:\OneDrive\Serienummer\01\%year%-%month%-%day%\PIC\NVR_ch01*.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:start
set year=%date:~6,4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set currentpath = D:\OneDrive\Serienummer\01\%year%-%month%-%day%\PIC\NVR_ch01*.jpg 
set targetpath = D:\WEBCAMS\Testkamera\0101.jpg
move %currentpath% %targetpath%
timeout /t 120
goto start
```

^this finds the date and time and moves the file every 120 seconds until you close cmd